# AWS EC2 Ubuntu 22.04 LTS session timeout not working (ClientAliveInterval, ClientAliveCountMax)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, session

I installed an AWS EC2 instance using Ubuntu:

```
ubuntu@ip-aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd:~$ lsb_release -ds
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
```

I was using the following simple tutorials to set the `ClientAliveInterval` and `ClientAliveCountMax`:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-increase-ssh-connection-timeout-in-linux

https://www.tecmint.com/increase-ssh-connection-timeout/

```
cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Gives:

```
... ^^ there's more above

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
ClientAliveInterval 360
ClientAliveCountMax 10
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
```

Important stuff:

```
TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
ClientAliveInterval 360
ClientAliveCountMax 10
```

After editing and saving the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I executed `sudo service ssh restart` and I closed the SSH session (I also tried `sudo systemctl reload sshd` as in the other tutorial), but:

After reconnecting and waiting for 10+ minutes, entering any char, my SSH client tells me that my connection has timed out (10 mins seems to be the default AWS setting, but I want one hour = 10 times 360 seconds).

**QUESTION:**

What's wrong?

How do you get the session timeout working *server-side* for AWS EC2 Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, that is **without any client session timeout properties** (I am connecting from multiple places, so I would like to avoid this).